# React - dynamic use of country-flag-icons library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-flag-icons library that allows to use flags icon in React in this way:

```
import Flags from 'country-flag-icons/react/3x2'

<Flags.US title="United States" className="..."/>
```

But how can i use it dynamically? Because the State code is returned through services.

I mean a some solution like this:

```
<Flags.{myVar} title="United States" className="..."/>
```

**EDIT**
This is my file:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Flags from "country-flag-icons/react/3x2";

const Person = ({ linkDetail, flagNationCode }) => (
  <Link to={linkDetail}>
   
    <div className="person-footer">
      <div className="info">
        <div className="label">{flagNationCode}</div>
        <div className="value">
            <Flags.US />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Link>
);

export default Person;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pick out the component into a variable that starts with a capital letter and use that as the component, e.g.:

```
const Person = ({ linkDetail, flagNationCode }) => {
  const Flag = Flags[flagNationCode];

  return (
    <Link to={linkDetail}>
      <div className="person-footer">
        <div className="info">
          <div className="label">{flagNationCode}</div>
          <div className="value">
            <Flag />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Comment: when using this solution in typescript:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`

Answer (score 3):

My workaround to assure typescript that the index surely exist within the Flags component is:

```
type FlagProps = {
  countryCode: string;
};

const Flag = ({ countryCode }: FlagProps) => {
  const FlagComponent = Flags[countryCode.toUpperCase() as keyof typeof Flags];
  return <FlagComponent />;
};
```

Notice the use of the `toUpperCase()` function because it is case-sensitive. Only `"US"` is accepted, while using `"us"` will get you an error.
and here's how I use the custom Flag component in my other components:

```
<Flag countryCode={countryCode} />
```

However, be careful when providing a country code. Providing a country code that does not exist in the Flags component will break your application.

```
<Flag countryCode={"en"} /> // throws an error because Flags.en does not exist. 
<Flag countryCode={"US"} /> // United States. OK.
<Flag countryCode={"GB"} /> // Great Britain. OK.
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the Flag you want in to a variable and then use it as a Component

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Flags from "country-flag-icons/react/3x2";

const Person = ({ linkDetail, flagNationCode }) => {
const Flag = Flags[flagNationCode];
return (
  <Link to={linkDetail}>
    <div className="person-footer">
      <div className="info">
        <div className="label">{flagNationCode}</div>
        <div className="value">
            <Flag />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Link>
)};

export default Person;
```

Comment: no this is not possibile, please see the EDIT section in my question

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having the problem: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`

Try this

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Flags from "country-flag-icons/react/3x2";

const Person = ({ linkDetail, flagNationCode }) => {

const obj: Record<string, FlagComponent> = Flags;
const Flag = Flags[flagNationCode];
return (
  <Link to={linkDetail}>
    <div className="person-footer">
      <div className="info">
        <div className="label">{flagNationCode}</div>
        <div className="value">
            <Flag />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Link>
)};

export default Person;
```

adding this conversion `const obj: Record<string, FlagComponent> = Flags;` worked for me